# find specific file extension with find command

Tags: unix, find, bsd

I would like to find any files within a given root that contain arbitrary extensions in the filename.
I saw this post:
[How to delete all files with certain suffix before file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839966/how-to-delete-all-files-with-certain-suffix-before-file-extension)

Based on that information, I tried this:

```
find . -iregex ".*\.\(wav\|aif\|wave\|aiff\)"
```

This seems like it *should* work, but I don't get any results printed to the terminal window.

Can anyone offer advice?  I'm on OSX 10.7

Thanks,
jml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(wav\|aif\|wave\|aiff\)"
```

You were missing escape, `\`, characters on the or, `|`, operators

Comment: apologies- i actually tried what you suggested.  i've modified my question.

Comment: Do non-regex `find` commands print output to the console?  You could try something like the following to pass the regex'ing responsibilities to a different utility:  
  
    `find . | grep -e ".*\.\(wav\|aif\)"`

Comment: that's perfect.  thanks... how can i pass it to a utility to delete them?

Comment: would it just be `find . | grep -e ".*\.(wav\|aif)" | rm` ?

Comment: hm; i get "xargs: unterminated quote" when i run this. :/  ... i can on the other hand print all the files that are found successfully, without piping to xargs.  what's wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

Is that an `emacs` style regex?

If not, try using `-regextype`.  From the `find` man page on Linux (archaic):

- `-regextype type`

  Changes the regular expression syntax understood by `-regex` and `-iregex` tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented types are `emacs` (this is the default),  `posix-awk`, `posix-basic`, `posix-egrep` and `posix-extended`.

---

On MacOS X, the manual page for `find` says:

> `-iregex pattern`
>
> Like `-regex`, but the match is case insensitive.
>
> `-regex pattern`
>
> True if the whole path of the file matches pattern using regular expression.  To match a file named '`./foo/xyzzy`', you can use the regular expression '`.*/[xyz]*`' or '`.*/foo/.*`', but not '`xyzzy`' or '`/foo/`'.

Some experimentation shows that:

```
find pdf -iregex ".*/.*.pdf"
```

finds a whole lot of PDF files in my folder full of them, but none of these variants find anything:

```
find pdf -iregex ".*/.*\.(pdf|doc|docx)"
find pdf -iregex ".*/.*\.\(pdf|doc|docx\)"
find pdf -iregex ".*/.*.(pdf|doc|docx)"
find pdf -iregex ".*/.*.\(pdf|doc|docx\)"
```

Consequently, one is forced to assume that the regexes supported by MacOS X (BSD) `find` do not include alternation (parentheses and pipes) amongst the recognized characters.  'Tis a pity: `man 7 re_format` implies it might, but it doesn't.  The `-regextype` option is not supported on MacOS X (BSD), it seems.

So, it may be simplest to install GNU `find`, or to do N separate searches for the N different file extensions, or do one search for files in general and use `egrep '\.(aff|wave?|aiff)$'` to catch the files you're interested in.  That rather assumes you don't use newlines in file names (spaces etc are OK, but newlines are not).